# How do I fix this error error"error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int (*)[]' to 'int *' "?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers

This is different from similar questions because I'm setting a pointer value to an address, instead of trying to assign an incompatible type... I think.

```
template <class Type>
class ArrayStack
{
private:
    int sz; // stack size
    int asz; // array size (implementation)
    Type* start; // address of first element
    Type arr[]; // Might need to intialize each element to 0!?
public:
    ArrayStack() { sz = 0; arr[0] = 0; asz = 0; start = &arr; }
/* other code... */
};
```

Comment: `start = arr`; should do the trick

Comment: But you should also specific the array size in the declaration.

Comment: What does that do? Also how do I close the question since you fixed it?

Comment: You can't have a "flexible array" data member in C++. `arr` needs a compile-time size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start = arr;` should do the trick.

- You can assign an array to a pointer, and will have the pointer set to the start of the array.

Also, an empty array specification:

```
Type arr[];
```

Not sure what that means. Probably the same as:

```
Type arr[0];
```

More normally:

```
Type arr[asz];
```

Of course the array size will need to be a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest use of `std::vector<Type> arr` instead of `Type arr[]`.

```
template <class Type>
class ArrayStack
{
private:
    int sz; // stack size
    int asz; // array size (implementation)

    // Type* start; // address of first element
    // Don't need this at all.
    // You can use &arr[0] any time you need a pointer to the
    // first element.
    std::vector<Type> arr;
public:

    // Simplified constructor.
    ArrayStack() : sz(0), asz(0), arr(1, 0) {}

/* other code... */
};
```